How to deal with missing data when performing a BSTS analysis
Data Description
I am using data from the Worldwide Governance Indicators (WGI), gathered by the World Bank. This dataset is a combination of multiple indicators from various sources, each with their own measurement techniques. Scores are gathered on a per country per year basis, and normalised through a min-max method to a range of 0-1. The following is a screenshot from my Excel file

I have columns for the Country Name, the Year as well as one column for each indicator relevant to my research. As you can see from the screenshot, there are quite a lot of missing values. This makes sense, because not all countries are scored on every indicator every year. This is where the question I have which I will discuss later is centered around.
General Goal
Based on the data described above, I want to make my own composite indicators in R. The idea is that for a subset of the indicators used by the WGI, I create a weighted average where the weights are determined by a Bayesian Structural Time Series model, specifically using a trend and slope components (local linear trend). The idea behind doing so is that due to difference in measuring methodology, scores are not equal. While 2 indicators might both score on a range from 1-10, one might use the full range while another might not. In that case, if a score of 8 is assigned, it is unclear whether that is a good score or not relative to the other scores.
I have chosen for a Bayesian approach due to the fact that I would like to include one of the indicators as prior knowledge due to it being representative for the dataset (i.e. covering the largest group of countries and having a representative sample). I have considered using an Unobserved Components Model (UCM) with a frequentionist approach instead, which I am debating on still, as I cannot estimate what will fit better with my data. However, after having read that BSTS is better at dealing with missing values, that was my first choice.
The Question
My question is how I can best deal with the missing values in computing the BSTS. Specifically, I have noticed that any NA values in the predictor (i.e. the prior knowledge, the representative indicator) seem to break the BSTS. Moreover, although the representative indicator is scored across the most countries, there are bound to be cases where the representative indicator is not scored whereas another one is, meaning there is no prediction.
I cannot impute missing values however, since this does not make sense with the nature of the data. Thus I am left with a problem. Does anyone have any ideas, tips, etc.? Or if you have a good source which you know discuss this, that is appreciated as well.
